# Import Eclipse project to Android studio project

Tags: eclipse, import, android-studio

In Android Studio is there any way to import Eclipse projects or do I have to copy and paste the files?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Add those information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try and use the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

> In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see
>   the Welcome to Android Studio window. Click Import Non-Android Studio
>   project. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it,
>   select the build.gradle file and click OK. In the following dialog,
>   leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not need to
>   specify the Gradle home.)

If you fail, be sure to install the latest ADT plugin. (v23) Click File -> Export. Open Android and then select Generate Gradle build files. Select the projects you want to export to Android Studio and then click Finish

In Android Studio click File -> Import Project. Locate your recently exported project then Create project from existing sources and click Next. You should be good now.