# Import Android projects in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, project

I want to use a sample Android project in Android Studio.
it project struct is different. how to use that sample project.

the project structure is like

[image]

what I tried:

I try to open projects as "Open projects as Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc..".
After opening, the application is not runnable using the run icon (icon not in green color).

Comment: Check console for errors in Android Studio and paste it here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Eclipse project to Android studio project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643400/import-eclipse-project-to-android-studio-project)

Comment: select android manifest file during import

Comment: it looks like a decompiled project from apk. If that so it will not be loaded properly.

Comment: @  Vivek Mishra, yes it is decompiled project. i try this for testing purpose. is it possible to run that  project?

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, You have to import the Project

```
File->New->import project
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to open Android studio and and import the project from there.

Comment: this is not useful in any way , be more clear with the answer